# Add a line to each item completed in a to do list

Tags: javascript, html

Thats my js

```
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var list = document.querySelectorAll("li")

function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
}

function addListAfterClick() {
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);

list.forEach(function(item) {
item.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelectorAll("li").classList.add("done");
    }); 
});
```

my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
        <li>Jello</li>
        <li>Spinach</li>
        <li>Rice</li>
        <li>Birthday Cake</li>
        <li>Candles</li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

What im trying to do is when i click on an item in the list a line is drawn to indicate that the item is completed. Im new to js , and this is fy first post here , i'm trying to understand events and all , i tried making a forEach loop with document.querySelectorAll("li") but it didn't work . At the moment the line is drawn only on the first item of the list

Comment: As-is, the code here doesn't run. Check your console for errors. Hint: `document.querySelectorAll()` doesn't return a single element.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Where you have

```
item.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelectorAll("li").classList.add("done");
    }); 
});
```

I think you want

```
item.addEventListener("click", function(e){
      e.target.classList.add("done");
    }); 
});
```

You can also use `this` instead of e.target